Change the tooltip of particular point
I have a button on tooltip in highchart.
I want to change the tooltip of the particular point on button click.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Highcharts Editable Data Label</title>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>

Below is the script
  Highcharts.AST.bypassHTMLFiltering = true;
  Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'line'
    },
    tooltip: {
        useHTML: true,
        formatter: function() {
            // Return the default tooltip content
            var tooltip = '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.x) + '<br/>' +
                Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
            
            // Add a button to the tooltip
            tooltip += '<br/><button onclick="changeTooltip(' + this.point.index + ')">Change Tooltip</button>';
            
            return tooltip;
        },
                            style: {
                              pointerEvents: 'auto'
                            }
    },
    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]
});

// Function to change tooltip for a specific point
function changeTooltip(pointIndex) {
    Highcharts.charts[0].update({
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                // Customize tooltip for this point
                return 'Customized Tooltip for Point ';
            },
                useHTML: true
            }})
}

I have tried above code but, when the button is clicked tooltip for all points are getting changed.
Have also tried with
point.update({tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                // Customize tooltip for this point
                return 'Customized Tooltip for Point ';
            },
                useHTML: true
            }});

but nothing happens

There are a variety of ways of doing this.
The way I did it here, was make three changes to your code:

Add a global array variable called customToolTips
Set that variable in your changeTooltip()
Access the variable in your formatter: function()

See the edits in the code snippet.
Note that after clicking the "Change Tooltip" button, you must move away from the point and then back on it, in order to see the new Tooltip text.


Highcharts.AST.bypassHTMLFiltering = true;
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  accessibility: {enabled:false}, // NOTE Just to get rid of the accessiblity warning in the console
  chart: {
    type: 'line'
  },
  tooltip: {
    useHTML: true,
    formatter: function() {
      // Return the default tooltip content
      var tooltip = '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>'
      if( customToolTips.length > this.point.index && customToolTips[this.point.index] ) {
        // Add the custom tooltip text
        tooltip += customToolTips[this.point.index];
      }
      else {
        // Original (non-custom) text
        tooltip += Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.x) + '<br/>'
      }

      tooltip += Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);

      // Add a button to the tooltip
      tooltip += '<br/><button onclick="changeTooltip(' + this.point.index + ')">Change Tooltip</button>';

      return tooltip;
    },
    style: {
      pointerEvents: 'auto'
    }
  },
  series: [{
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
  }]
});


let customToolTips = [];

// Function to change tooltip for a specific point
function changeTooltip(pointIndex) {
  // NOTE Store some custom text
  customToolTips[pointIndex] = `<div class="Custom">THIS IS CUSTOM for #${pointIndex}</div>`;
}
.container {
  margin: 10px;
  border: solid 4px yellow;
}
.Custom {
  color: red;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>


<div id="container" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>




Thanks!, it worked with a bit change. Had to use this.x or point.x instead of insed, as Index changes when we zoom the highchart and click the button.
